# Matlab comparison of two large matricies

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, comparison

I am trying to retrieve the index of exact matches (row-specific) between two large matricies. I have a n x 61 matrix A containing values from 0 to 9 and another n x 61 matrix B , whereas each row here contains values from 0 to 9 but mostly NaN (only 2 to 8 columns in each row of matrix B contain actual numbers). Matrix A can be expected to have between 1.5 million and 3 million rows, whereas matrix B has around 0.2 to 0.5 million rows. Here is an example of the setup:

```
% create matrix a with random data

dataSample = [0 9];
numRows = 1000000;
numCols = 61;
A = randi(dataSample,numRows,numCols);

% create matrix B with random data
numRows = 100000;
numCols = 61;
numColsUse = 2:8;
dataRange = 0:9;
B = NaN(numRows,numCols);
for i = 1:size(B,1)

    % randomly selet number of columns to fill
    numColsFill = datasample(numColsUse,1);

    % randomly select column index from available columns
    colIdx = datasample([1:numCols],numColsFill);

    % randomly select values from 0 to 9
    numFill = datasample([0:9],numColsFill);

    % insert numbers at respective column in matrix B
    B(i,colIdx) = numFill;

end
```

I want to compare every single row of matrix A with the entire matrix B and find exact matches, where the numbers of matrix B match the numbers of matrix A at their respective positions (columns) - hence the NaN in matrix B are to be ignored.

I can achieve the desired result using cellfun, where I slice matrix A in several subsets and then use a custom function to compare the rows of the subset with each row in matrix B, like so:

```
% put all rows of matrix B in single cell
cellB = {B};

% take subset of matrix A and convert to cell array
subA = A(1000:5000,:);
subA = num2cell(subA,2);

% prepare cellB to meet cellfun conditions
cellB = repmat(cellB, [size(subA,1) 1]);

% apply cellfun to retrieve index of each exact match
idxContainer = cellfun(@findMatch, cellB, subA, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Function findMatch looks as follows:

```
function [ idx ] = LTableEval( cellB,  subA )

    idxCheckLT = lt(cellB, repmat(subA, [size(cellB,1) 1]));
    idxCheckGT = gt(cellB, repmat(subA, [size(cellB,1) 1]));
    idxCheck = idxCheckLT + idxCheckGT;
    idxSum = sum(idxCheck,2);
    idx = find(idxSum == 0);

end
```

This approach works, but it appears to be very inefficient, especially RAM-wise, as the cellfun requires all inputs to have the same size and hence a multiplication of the same data sets. Any ideas on how to tackle this problem in a more efficient way? Many thanks!

Comment: matrix subtraction?

Comment: `A-B==0`? Substraction seems teh way to go yes

Comment: i agree, substraction makes a lot of sense for the actual comparison and is much better than my current method. However, this does not solve my more fundamental problem that I want to find an efficient way to substract every single row of A with every row of B. Any ideas on that front? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution was provided to me in the mathworks forum:

```
matches = cell(size(B, 1), 1);
for Brow = 1:size(B, 1)
    Bcols = find(~isnan(B(Brow, :)));
    fdsmatchedrows = find(all(A(:, Bcols) == B(Brow, Bcols), 2));
    matches{Brow} = [matchedrows, repmat(Brow, size(matchedrows))];
end
matches = cell2mat(matches);
```

This only works with R2016a and later. Alternatively, replace the second row in the for-loop with this line:

```
matches{Brow} = find(all(bsxfun(@eq, A(:, Bcols), B(Brow, Bcols)), 2));
```

The result is identical to the solution Jed provided, but I think through the use of bsxfun a little more quicker. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
for br = 1:size(B,1)
  abs_diff = abs(repmat(B(br,:),[size(A,1) 1]) - A);
  abs_diff(isnan(abs_diff)) = 0;
  match = abs_diff == 0;
  ind = find(sum(match,2)==size(match,2));
  matches{br} = [repmat(br,[length(ind) 1]) ind];
end
matches = cell2mat(matches');
```

Comment: Hi Jed, thanks for your suggestion. This already works much better and I like the idea of going looping through each row of B rather than A and that there is no need for "slicing" A into sub parts. However, a signle iteration of the loop is still above 1s for me so even when I use parfor, I am looking at a very long computation time... any further ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah... use a mex function.